# Can my body learn to split at 25?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, safety, flexibility

The title pretty much says it all. I am a little flexible like, I can get to touch my knees with my head. When I was young, I could try side (right splits) but never comfortably. Now I won't even dare based on my condition but:

- Based on my age/bone maturity is it healthy and possible to pursue this new goal
  of mine which is; to be able to do but front and side splits ?

If possible, what are some good daily starting exercises?

Comment: This would be a better fit at fitness.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your age, there is no reason why you cannot. It won't happen for everyone, but if you did them at an earlier age then you should be able to do them again. But make no mistake, it is going to take some sustained and regular training to achieve it, and if you stop stretching once you've achieved the splits then you will gradually lose your flexibility again. I would recommend [PNF stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNF_stretching) as a very efficient way to stretch, although it takes some practice to be able to execute it correctly and is more difficult to do without a partner.

> Why are front splits much more challenging than right splits ?

Because you are a male. I have been told that due to anatomical reasons most males find it far more difficult to achieve a front split than a side split, and it's the opposite for females. I don't know the exact reason, but it's to do with the structure and shape of the pelvis and the attachment points for muscles and [ligaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliofemoral_ligament).

Comment: I second PNF stretching techniques.  The only restriction to people being able to do splits isn't age, but rather the angle of the femur head in the hip socket, which, for some, is set such they can never fully get splits.  Otherwise, it's really just a matter of time and patience.  And, along with flexibility - make sure to do strength exercises at the far ranges of your range of motion to stabilize your joint!

Answer (score 3):

Your potential for a split will depend on a few things. If you look at Tom Kurz's work on stretching it will go into more detail, but in short, do deep goblet squats (or front squats) and as you build your strength move apart your legs.

The reason is the correct positioning for a box or front split is actually a very, very deep squat.

Although if your aim is to become better at kicking, static stretching is quite pointless and not a good use of your time, other than to cool down at the end of a workout perhaps.

If you want to improve your kicking abilities, focus on dynamic stretching and strength training, this is the best DVD I've seen on the subject; http://www.stadion.com/power-high-kicks-with-no-warm-up/

I can, at anytime, even after my current long absence from training still kick to the head with no warm up as a result of this training.